# Coordinate Systems in MarkLogic Server

Tags: system, marklogic, coordinate

What coordinate systems are supprted by Marklogic server?

Answer (score 2):

MarkLogic can operate in 2 modes for geospatial coordinates: and WGS84 and Raw.

Comment: This of course won't stop you from ingesting or distributing data in other coordinate systems, you'll just have to transform/project on ingest or distribution.  The key point is that at the lowest level queries are run in either WGS84 or Raw.  I have seen and built systems that work with all sorts of military grid references, local government surveying standards specified in yards, etc.